# Deleting elements that appeare more than once in the list and leaving only one element

Tags: python-2.7

I have a small question.
how can i check if a list has identical elements and if the list has identical elements, how can leave only one of those elements in the list?

For example, i wrote this code:

```
def courses_per_student(tuple_lst):
    courses={}
    new_tuple_lst=[]
    for i in range(len(tuple_lst)):
            new_tuple_lst.append((str(tuple_lst[i][0]).lower(),(str(tuple_lst[i][1]).lower())))
    for m in new_tuple_lst:      
       if not courses.has_key(m[0]):
            courses[m[0]]=[m[1]]
       else:
           courses[m[0]]=courses[m[0]]+[m[1]]
    return courses
```

**which for**:   courses_per_student([("Rina", "Math"), ("Yossi", "Chemistry"), ("Riki", "python"), ("Rina", "math"), ("Yossi", "biology")])
**returns**:
{'rina': ['math', 'math'], 'yossi': ['chemistry', 'biology'], 'riki': ['python']}

**I want that 'math' will appere only once in the list.**
thankyou

Comment: You can convert the list to a `set`: https://repl.it/repls/DefiantVibrantHalcyon

Answer (score 2):

```
def uniqode(list):
    demolist = []
    for el in list:
        if el in demolist:
            continue
        demolist.append(el)
    return demolist
```

Answer (score 1):

...

```
        for m in new_tuple_lst:      
           if not courses.has_key(m[0]):
                courses[m[0]]=[m[1]]
           elif m[1] not in courses[m[0]]:
               courses[m[0]]=courses[m[0]]+[m[1]]
```

Use set instead of list should also do it if the order does not matter.